# How to avoid a problematic file in loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am looping throgh lots of files but the code stops when it encounters a problem with one file:

```
files= paste("C:\\Users\\data_ ", data1$column, "_",  data1$row, ".txt", sep="")
for(i in 1:length(files)){
wf <- read.table(files[i], sep=' ', header=TRUE)
wf=subset(wf, !is.na(scan))

here, for instance, `wf` would be:
[1] date1  date2  scan         
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

do stuf...............
}
```

so the code here will stop and through this error:

```
Error in data.frame(date = resf$wdDate, obs, mod = daf): 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I want the loop to just ignore this (problematic) file and does not go further in the loop but goes to read the next file and so on

Comment: take a look at `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `try( ..code.. )` or the `tryCatch( ..code.. )` statement. Here is the best link that I know explaining it, the section on exception handling is further down.

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html

Here is a simple loop using `try` that ignores file read errors

```
files <- c("f1","f2","f3")
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  try(
    {
      print(files[i])
      df <- read.csv(files[i])
    },silent=T
  )
}
```

Here is a another one using `tryCatch` that ignores file read errors

```
 files <- c("f1","f2","f3")  

 for (i in 1:length(files)){
      tryCatch(
        {
          print(files[i])
          df <- read.csv(files[i])
        },
        error = function(c) "error",
        warning = function(c) "warning",
        message = function(c) "message"
      )
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit weird compared to the syntax in other languages. I posted a simple example that should get you furthur.

Comment: Actually try is simpler, and I modified my answer to reflect this.